# how to make Coded UI tests stable?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have an application which has two parts, a WPF part and a Web part. I've written some coded ui to test it. However the coded ui is not stable and sometimes fails and sometimes passes. The reason it fails is that it fails to locates some of the controls! I try to use `WaitForControlExist(8000)` but it doesn't solve the problem. I previously used `WaitForControlReady(8000)` but it makes it even worst and the reason was mainly because of some of the controls like `WPFButton` so I decided to use `WaitForControlExist` instead. How can I make the test stable that they do not fail.

when I look at the logs, those controls that the coded ui could not pick up actually exist in the screen and I don't know why it couldn't pick them up.

Comment: `those controls that the coded ui could not pick up actually exist in the screen and I don't know why it couldn't pick them up` start by solving *that*.

Comment: sorry I didn't get the point

Comment: Do you run test on the same system? I mean, do you test simultaneously both WPF and Web part withing one test?

Comment: I got both types of test, one which only involves WPF and one which involves both WPF and web. both tests sometimes fail though.